# Is there a way to change the size of fields within a form using CSS or HTML?

Tags: html, css

The form boxes/fields are generally pretty large. I was wondering if there was a way to make them smaller in CSS or HTML since there is no other sizing options. Thanks!

Comment: Give those inputs a class then set the width to what ever you want `.myInput{width: 200px; max-width: 210px}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS for adjusting the height, width, and alignment of the whole form.

```
form {
      width:550px;
      height:450px;
      margin:auto;
      position:relative;
}
```

CSS for adjusting the height and width of your input fields.

```
input {
       width:375px;
       height: 25px;
      }
```

Also Html using:

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
      Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="35"><br>
      PIN: <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4" size="4"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please see this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Using HTML.

Read this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp

So use it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="2">
```

Answer (score 1):

The sizes of fields can be set in CSS using [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) and `height` properties. The sizes may also be indirectly affected by font size settings. In addition, padding settings may have an effect.

For `input type=text`, the width can also be set using the `size` attribute, but this gives consistent (across browsers) results only when a monospace font is used. Example:

```html
<input size="8" style="font-family: Consolas, monospace" value="12345678">
```

For `textarea` elements, the `rows` and `cols` attributes can also be used.